# Targetting Textbox Control via Javascript API

Tags: rightnow-crm

I've a textbox control (drag-dopped via the "Insert Control" tab) on my workspace. But since that control has no name or ID, I was wondering if I could target that control via Javascript API to get or set its value. Is this even possible?

[image: Agent Console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS API interacts with the UI based on object field name, so your easiest option is a custom field that exists on the workspace object; then you can populate it as per the docs.  If you don't want to keep the data, then you could implement a Custom Process Model to remove the info from the record on save.  Another option would be an addin that displays a browser control where you implement an alternative to the JS API and use the add-in to populate data in your workspace controls directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm aware of the usage of the JS API when a custom field or standard field is present on the workspace. However, in my case I'm required to use a textbox control and not a DB field. From what I understand of your post, I won't be able to target that textbox control with JS API and will have to depend on add-in to populate/read value from it, right?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is just to add a custom field (a DB field), and add the data to it.  It's not the best for a clean schema, but makes what you are trying to do much easier.  The add-in route is the alternative if you absolutely cannot use a custom field.  That approach, however, is a much more complex effort requiring your addin to be aware of what the web page is doing as well at passing that data on to the workspace context or just displaying the text area itself as a custom control.